# Asp.net web services, how to keep some members private

Tags: asp.net, web-services, monodevelop

I have an asp.net web service project. This project contains a few classes declared in their own files. One of these classes is called clsUser.

The clsUser consists of string firstName, string passWord and bool enabled (a lot more actually but just to keep it simple). I want the creator of the client code to be able to access the firstName and passWord members so changes can be made, but I do not want them accessing the enabled bool.

So I made firstName and passWord public, and made enabled internal (so that I may access it in my web service code). The thing is, I have to use MonoDevelop to get this .Net web service up on our linux servers and anything declared as internal is not seen by Mono.

Is there another way I can keep certain member accessible in my web service code but keep it hidden from clients??

Comment: Minor code things you should consider.  1. Drop "cls" in front of User.  It adds nothing and is currently considered evil by MS and a whole lot of other people.  2. Regarding "passWord".  Typically you capitalize on word breakers.  Password is actually one word so the proper way is to just call it "password".. unless it's a public property at which point it should be "Password"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a separate 'surrogate' class that contains only the members you're willing to expose, and return an instance of that populated from the original clsUser instance, instead of an instance of clsUser.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry to ask but can you please post a short example? I think I know what you mean but I'd like to be 100% sure.

Comment: If you have a class that has `UserName` and `UserID` and `Password` properties and this is your main 'model' for the user object (or whatever) then just create a separate class called `UserLite` (or something) that can be populated from the main class and is used as the actual return type from the service. In other words, almost exactly the same class, except without the `Password` property.